# Monkey X Export Setup

Tags: inno-setup, monkey-x

I'm using Monkey X Studio since yesterday and want to "export" the game I've made with it for Windows (glfw). So I built the Game in Release Configuration, took the .exe and the data Folder and created an InnoSetup setup for it. When someone else installed and started the game, the error message "OpenAL32.dll is missing" appeared. 
"The Application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the Application".
Do you have any idea how I can fix this issue and export a setup for windows?

Luca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply "OpenAL32.dll is missing.

You need to copy this dll to target computer during installation.

This dll may be present in e.g. System folder on your computer but is missing on different computer.

Find the dll and add it to installer (copy to appropriate folder).

Comment: Thanks it worked with the silent installier for OpenAL :)